# How do I match a vector of tuples and its content using a single check?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I want to match a vector of tuples and its content using a single check. If the value inside the tuple is equal to `some_value` (a `usize`) then I do something, for every other case I do something else.

I handle it like this with basic logic:

```
if myvector.is_empty() {
    // do action 1
} else if myvector.last().unwrap().0 == some_value {
    // do action 2
} else {
    // do action 1
}
```

This does what I want, but I feel there's a more idiomatic way to do it.
I've been trying with `match`:

```
match myvector.last() {
    Some(t) => match t.0 == some_value {
        true => unimplemented!("do action 2"),
        false => unimplemented!("do action 1"),
    },
    None => unimplemented!("do action 1"),
}
```

This also works, but I'm trying to figure out a better syntax to cover a single case once only (`action1`).

Comment: What type is `t.0`? Can you match against that directly or do you have to use `==`?

Comment: `t.0` is a `char` value. so yeah direct comparison is ok. But i need to check for the `Option` first anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the following to work:

```
match myvector.last() {
    Some(t) if t.0 == some_value => unimplemented!("do action2"),
    _ => unimplemented!("do action1"),
}
```

Comment: That is called a "pattern guard", and is the correct solution: there is (currently) no way to provide a non-literal value in a pattern (a non-constructor name will always introduce a new binding).

Comment: @Jason that is a confusion on my side, I'll fix it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: It's also possible to do something like `Some((a, b)) if a == some_value` if you want to deconstruct the tuple into individual variables as well.

Comment: @Stargateur can you maybe argument your expert opinion ? Not that I doubt it but I think the reasoning would be enlightening.

Comment: @DenysSéguret expert was a joke related to the answer :p anyway it's too long to explain, I feel guard often have a better solution and I think it's break the concept of pattern matching, adding a logical if to it make the compiler say it's not a exhaustive match and you always need to add a default case. I think most of the time a match guard imply a fishy code. I didn't provide any explanation because I know most people will not agree with my opinion. It's more like a feeling I don't like match guard, each time I wanted to use them there was a compiler limitation or a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [slice pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/slice-patterns.html) to extract the last element, and deconstruct the tuple directly in the pattern:

```
fn test_last(v: &[(u32, u32)], testval: u32) -> u32 {
    match v {
        [.., (val, _)] if *val == testval => {
            // action 2
        }
        _ => {
            // action 1
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d9e11c5bd82c10aac9dfcf79f6cc818e)

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```rust
if let Some(_) = my_vector.last().filter(|(n, _)| n == some_value) {
    // do action 2
} else {
    // do action 1
}
```